# Is it possible to share common code between .Net6 and .Net Framework Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I develop mostly for .Net Framework 4.6.2. Lately we have decided to start developing for .Net 6. I have my own Nuget Server. I would like to develop a suite of Utilities and publish them to our Nuget Server. These Utilities should be consumable by both .Net 6 apps and .Net Framework 4.6.2 apps. The Utilities contain a lot of code common across both targets.

What I tried doing was creating a new Solution comprising a .Net Standard Common lib (A) where I could place all the common code. Then two other libs, one in .Net 6 (B) and one in .Net Framework 4.6.2 (C) each referencing the common .Net Standard lib. I then publish B and C to my Nuget Server.

Then to test, I create a new .Net 6 Console App and add Nuget Package (B), It sees B's code only. It has no visibility of the Common lib (A). Its a similar problem if I create a new .Net Framework Console App and add Nuget Package (C).

Is it possible to share common code across a .Net 6 lib and a .Net Framework lib, then consume these from Nuget and have access to the common code? I don't want to end up writing the common code twice for B and C if I can help it.

Many thanks.

Comment: *"I then publish B and C to my Nuget Server"* - There's your problem. You're not also publishing library A as a package. Packages B and C shouldn't contain library A within them.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I should publish all 3 as packages and have B and C dependent on A at a Nuget package level?  Interesting, I might try that.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You'll publish package A with all of its unit tests passing so you can be sure it does its job right independently. Then projects B and C have `<PackageReference/>`s to package A. If you're using MSBuild to pack it, packages B and C will include the package dependency automatically.

Comment: You could also avoid publishing package chains by including the common code in both projects B and C. That way you end up with only a single DLL/package for each TFM. To do this, you add an MSBuild item like `<Compile Include="../Common/**/*.cs" LinkBase="Common" />` in both project B and C. Since this effectively makes the code multi-targeted, it would need to compile against both net6.0 and net462. Differences can be handled by preprocessor directives, but YMMV. At some point it makes more sense to do it the nuget way and publish an A package even though it is for internal use only.

Comment: One of the benefits of NuGet packages is the ability to be granular. Let's say there were two more packages, **D** (.NET 6) and **E** (.NET 4.6.2), and both also depend on library A. If a .NET 6 application needs to use both B and D, having A integrated into both of them means that the functionality is duplicated. Including library A (the DLL) in each dependant package could cause a conflict, especially when versioning comes into play. Distributing A as a separate package is by far the best way to go.